# TYPO3 (with extbase) fluid: display image src with absolute path

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase

For an XML Export I need to output the absolute path of 2 images. Image1 is located in /typo3conf/ext/app/Resources/Public/Images/image1.png
and Image2 is located in /uploads/tx_extensionname/image2.png

For the life of me I cannot find a way to get the absolute paths of the images. What I tried:

```
<f:uri.image absolute="1" src="EXT:app/Resources/Public/Images/image1.png"/>
```

Which returns the following error:

```
Argument "absolute" was not registered.
```

I also tried f:uri.resource , which works for image1, but, of course, doesn't for image2 because there is no extensionName.

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `absolute` argument for the `f:uri.image` view helper was added only recently in TYPO3 7.6.0. See the [changelog](https://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3.CMS/Releases/7.6/Feature#Feature:_.2364286_-_Added_absolute_url_option_to_uri.image_and_image_viewHelper):

> **Feature: #64286 - Added absolute url option to uri.image and image viewHelper**
>
> The ImageViewhelper and Uri/ImageViewHelper got a new option absolute. With this option you are able to force the ViewHelpers to output an absolute url.

**I'd suggest upgrading to TYPO3 7.6**.

If that's not possible for you for any reason, you can extend the `f:uri.image` view helper. The code below is untested, but should work for 6.2 LTS (I've borrowed parts of the code from `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Service\ImageService` in 7.6):

```
namespace Vendor\ExtensionKey\ViewHelpers\Uri;

use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Uri\ImageViewHelper;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class ImageViewHelper extends ImageViewHelper
{
    public function render(
        $src = null,
        $image = null,
        $width = null,
        $height = null,
        $minWidth = null,
        $minHeight = null,
        $maxWidth = null,
        $maxHeight = null,
        $treatIdAsReference = false,
        $absolute = false
    ) {
        $uri = parent::render($src, $image, $width, $height, $minWidth, $minHeight, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $treatIdAsReference);

        if ($absolute) {
            $uriPrefix = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->absRefPrefix;
            $uri = GeneralUtility::locationHeaderUrl($uriPrefix . $uri);
        }

        return $uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thank you very much! updating is unfortunately not an option right now but I will implement your extension of f:uri.image

Comment: @Chi, just out of curiosity, did this solution work for you? Anything that I can/should improve in my answer?

Comment: i actually tried your solution - but in my case i failed on making the viewhelper work in Typo3 6.2. - it wont even load (Argument "absolute" was not registered.)